# Conditional select using jq

Tags: jq

I have this below json format, I want to take the list of "id" which satisfies the condition

in this below I want to take the **id** which has matchers.value as **dev-stack**  and status.state as **active**

```
{
 "status": "success",
 "data": [
   {
     "id": "b5e7f85d",
     "matchers": [
       {
         "name": "stack",
         "value": "dev-stack",
         "isRegex": true
       }
     ],
     "startsAt": "2020-07-13T07:17:36Z",
     "endsAt": "2020-07-15T07:15:44Z",
     "updatedAt": "2020-07-13T07:15:59.643692023Z",
     "createdBy": "api",
     "comment": "Silence",
     "status": {
       "state": "active"
     }
   },
   {
     "id": "1fdaa4b5",
     "matchers": [
       {
         "name": "stack",
         "value": "qa-stack",
         "isRegex": true
       }
     ],
     "startsAt": "2020-07-10T13:19:12Z",
     "endsAt": "2020-07-10T13:20:55.510739499Z",
     "updatedAt": "2020-07-10T13:20:55.510739499Z",
     "createdBy": "api",
     "comment": "Silence",
     "status": {
       "state": "expired"
     }
   }    
 ]
}
```

Comment: This is trivial, what have you tried on your own?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried and got the expected data... Thanks...

BTW below is the answer 

```jq '.data | .[] | select((.status | .state == "active") and (.matchers | .[] | .value == "dev-stack")) | .id' ```

Comment: Nice. Consider posting that as an answer so that we can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses [update assignment |=](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=), [map](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) and [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) to update `.data`.
Note it avoids an undesirable cartesian product if multiple `.matchers` meet the criteria by using [any](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)).

```
.data |= map(select(
  (.matchers | any(.value=="dev-stack")) and (.status.state=="active")
))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHLbsIwELznKyyfEgmivEwaSxzaT2g5teJg7KVNS9IQOwgEfHtqOw2BtqIXLsl6Z2Y93nlft60vmGLoMEUFq1wJK@DKRa5fMMXfoJYHVu5cf8NWDaDpFGEBm7FUjH9gz0OsFJqqj6qR9tdxGFf5BrCHPK9t9w7CHQNTXTWcg5R4pLvmYt17cRBCe/NBCOfCsBYE0uUdEYZm272bno4GicVLVoAdb52NzhDr3ECD8XM4l4/wCltNUHUDPXDsinl/vdbVSt4rMycKomAcpOMwngUpDVMaT55PPqEUP2nE0ghNkoHWVPrtIP4cSCjJ/EkSTzINxIOG12A0DzujYVU@AJ9FAaUd9ZSvoOSAz3x3ez/tyrbsPr5DcoYHH0e/kwiXgrFkQW6ZxJrdNohgFsY0zGgYXQ3C0qKAEuKTMEjjLMmy/yK5rrl1JLCt8hrERSamctDcOX4B)